# Typescript + Angular 1.x, directive w/ require:'^someCtrl' failing with 'unknown provider'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Using Angular with Typescript. I have a Tabs controller based on Angular Bootstrap UI tabs that works in pure Angular, but when I move it over to our Typescript style, I can't get one directive (OneTab) to find the controller for the (parent) directive (TabSet).

`ERROR: Unknown provider: tabProvider <- tab`

I've tried a bunch of different ways of doing this but none of them make it work properly like the non-Typescript version does.

Ex: [Angular-only Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/baST7F3eoy9h69lU2aRr?p=preview)

We're using a modular model, which is tied together with a config file each for directives, controllers, etc. This structure is working fine except for this tab directive experiment.

```
module app.directives {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .directive('tabSet', ()=> new TabSet())
    .directive('oneTab', ()=> new OneTab())
;
```

}

```
module app.directives {
    interface ITabScope extends ng.IScope {
        active:boolean;
    }

    export class OneTab implements ng.IDirective {
        priority = 0;
        restrict = 'E';
        transclude = true;
        require = '^tabsetCtrl';
        scope = {
            heading: '@'
        };
        template = '<div role="tabpanel" ng-transclude ng-show="active"></div>';
        link = function (scope:ITabScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attr:ng.IAttributes, tabsetCtrl:any) {
            scope.active = false;
            tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);
        }
    }
}


module app.directives {
    import TabSetController = app.controllers.TabSetController;
    export class TabSet implements ng.IDirective{
        priority = 0;
        restrict = 'E';
        transclude = true;
        scope = {};
        templateUrl = 'layout/tabset.html';
        controller = TabSetController;
        controllerAs = 'tabsetCtrl';
        bindToController = true;
    } 
}


module app.controllers {
'use strict';
export class TabSetController {
    tabs:Array<any>;
    tab:any;
    selectedTab:any;

    constructor(tab:any, selectedTab:any) {
        this.tabs = [];
        this.addTab(tab);
        this.select(selectedTab);
        console.log("in constructor");
    }

    addTab(tab?:any) {
        if(tab){
            this.tabs.push(tab);
            if (this.tabs.length === 1) {
                tab.active = true
            }
        }

    };

    select(selectedTab?:any) {
        if (selectedTab){
            angular.forEach(this.tabs, function (tab:any) {
                if (tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
                    tab.active = false;
                }
            });
            selectedTab.active = true;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with your directives, as far as I can tell, it's with your controller class. Angular assumes that any parameters in the constructor method of a controller are services that you want to inject - seeing as you're trying to pass in parameters called `tab` and `selectedTab`, it's searching for services to inject with those names. There's no service named `tab`, so you get an unknown provider error.

Comment: The tab is a variable not a service so how would I write my typescript so that I can make room for that parameter  in the method call and not have an expect the service injection?

Comment: Actually tab is a object that's being passed from the html via transclsion

Comment: There's not really any reason to have non-service parameters in the constructor of a controller, as you never instantiate them yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'a object that's being passed from the html via transclusion'. Transclusion won't ever cause anything to be passed to the constructor of your controller.

Comment: So just leave the addTab() and select() methods out of the constructor altogether won't Typescript complain?

Comment: Yep, if you remove the constructor parameters and the calls to `addTab` and `select` it will fix your issue.

Comment: Cool I'll try that as soon as I get back to my desk. Thanks.

Comment: Ok,  that changed the situation :)

Comment: Now I get an error that Controller 'tabsCtrl', required by directive 'oneTab', can't be found.  Which was my original problem that got overshadowed by the other error.

Comment: `require = '^tabsetCtrl'` should be replaced with `require = '^tabSet'`, as it is in your non-TypeScript example. You're specifying the name of the parent directive, not the name of the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104690/discussion-between-joe-clay-and-maxrocket).